# Unable to set GridLayout height programatically

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to implement swipe actions on ListView for each element. Whole view is AbsoluteLayout, with two GridLayouts: one acting as "foreground"(list element) and other as "background" (swipe actions). I want them both to have equal height of "foreground" (which is dynamic and differs for every list element).

I succesfully implemented this on Android - I call a method on layoutChanged event

```
onLayoutChanged(args: EventData) {
    const foregroundNotificationTemplate = (<AbsoluteLayout>(args.object)).getChildAt(1);
    const backgroundButtons = (<AbsoluteLayout>args.object).getChildAt(0);
    backgroundButtons.height = foregroundNotificationTemplate.getActualSize().height;
}
```

This unfortunatelly is not working on iOS. I tried to access Frame and UiView, but with no success - it has height of background content.

Demo presenting the problem on Nativescript Playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=4LRwDC

Comment: RadListView comes with swipe actions feature out of the box, may I ask if you have any specific reason for doing this on your own?

Comment: I know about this component, but it does not meet my expectations and I cannot implement feature I need with it. Besides whole implementation was quite easy and quick, and so far this is the only issue I am having.

Comment: iOS doesn't support dynamic height on ListView, you will have to refresh the item when you do. May be if you can share the Playground Sample, I can take a look.

Comment: I added link to playground in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use `AbsoluteLayout` as you are animating the position with translate which is possible with any layout. So using `GridLayout` instead of `AbsoluteLayout` should solve your problem on both platforms and you may also get rid `layoutChanged` event for measuring height.

Also note that your ListView item template can not be dynamic, you should not use ngIf or anything that would alter the structure of the list item, use multiple templates instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for working solution, thats what Manoj proposed: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yXggcv